# Not able to dispay pbf(mapbox vector tile) using openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mapbox, vector-tiles, osm.pbf

i am trying to display my own created vector tiles(.pbf), they are not getting displayed with no error on console of inspect element.
I am dispaying them by using a simple example html file at:
[here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/mapbox-vector-tiles.html)

I just have changed  the url to look for vector tiles on the local server instead of mapbox server.

When i try to display the pbf files from mapbox server:
, it gets displayed. Also i have downloaded these mapbox pbf files and served same files from local server they get displayed.

But the pbf files which i have created from geojson file using tippecanoe cant be displayed by openlayers.The generated pbf files are correct as i am able to dislay them using mapbox js script.
I have cors on,server's content encoding is also gzip.
Sample pbf file which is not getting displayed by the attached code but by tileserver-gl(mapbox script) can be downloaded from
 [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5dvhl2e2w4x9h2/0.pbf?dl=0)

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mapbox Vector Tiles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.5.0/examples/resources/mapbox-streets-v6-style.js"></script>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v3.1.1/mapbox.js'></script>
    <style>
        .map {
            background: #f8f4f0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<script>
    var key = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWhvY2V2YXIiLCJhIjoiRk1kMWZaSSJ9.E5BkluenyWQMsBLsuByrmg';

    var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.VectorTile({
                declutter: true,
                source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
                    attributions: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> ' +
                    '© <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">' +
                    'OpenStreetMap contributors</a>',
                    format: new ol.format.MVT(),

                    url: 'http://localhost:8000/tippecanoe_tiles/' + '{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
                    //url: 'https://{a-d}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6/' +
                    //          '{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?access_token=' + key

                }),
                style: createMapboxStreetsV6Style(ol.style.Style, ol.style.Fill, ol.style.Stroke, ol.style.Icon, ol.style.Text)
            })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you should define your own style (in Openlayers way) to display tippecanoed data?

Comment: Hi unibasil,i have tried that too.I commented the line style: and it works(maps get displayed without style) with their pbf tiles but not with mine.So that means i have taken out the possibility that style might be an issue thats causing tiles not to be displayed.If thats what you are talking about

Comment: You need to create ol style objects, you don't need any mapbox client scripts at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're using OpenLayers 4.5 instead of OpenLayers 5.X, try uploading your OpenLayers version.

Comment: I think this can be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Your right, still that is the fault, I had that same issue last week, vector tiles is an openlayers5 feature, I will do it in a comment next time.

Comment: *Why* should he update to 5.X? Why does this solve the issue? This would go a long way to improving this post for future readers.